# Create two arrays in numpy with random int from a uniform distr

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Each number in "a" array should be >= with the number in the same position from "b" array. Range 0,10

```
a = np.random.randint(0,10,300)

b=[]
for i in a:
   b = np.random.randint(0,i,300)
```

Got a ValueError: low >= high

Then I tried i+1 but values in b exceed the ones from a

Comment: What is the goal here? Are you trying to generate two random arrays with this constraint?

Comment: `i + 1` will not make the result exceed the corresponding element in `a`, you forget to append it to `b` but cover `b`. It may be better to use `np.random.randint(0, a + 1)` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to create two random arrays ensuring `a >= b`, you can use:

```
b, a = np.sort(np.random.randint(0, 10, (2, 300)), axis=0)

assert (a>=b).all()
```

Comment: Ok thanks, just a question. Why do we need the assert statement?

Comment: @vartholomeos007 this is just a check that all values of a are >= to that of b. This raises an error is this is not True, which should never happen. You can remove it ;)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. That works. Another question as I am still learning and this is the only way to do it. Why does it sort based on the second array and the numbers are random in each array?

Comment: It doesn't sort based on the second array, but on the second **dimension**, ensuring that all values of the bottom row are greater than that of the top. Note that you can also use `a = np.random.randint(0,10,300) ; b = np.random.randint(0, a+1)`